# How to Get Rid of Undefined Index in Carousel

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am working on developing an image carousel that looks something like the following:

[image]

I will go through and style everything correctly once I have all of the JavaScript and JQuery functioning properly so it won't display 100% like the picture below at it's present stage so don't worry about that. My current issue is that one of the smaller thumbnails is showing up as "undefined" under the img with id `img3` and another under `img1` when you click through the carousel. I know that the issue is from my index trying to call something at the end or at the beginning of my array that doesn't exist. How do I fix this in my JavaScript so that the first index in the array shows up rather than an index that doesn't exist?

I stripped out the irrelevant code below so you can see what I have so far:

**HTML**

```
<div id="carouselContainer">
<!--Add carousel and lightbox "view larger" button here-->
<img id="productImage" src="#">
<div id="viewLarger"></div>
<div id="carouselWrapper">
    <button id="prev">Prev</button>
    <div id="carousel">
        <img id="img1" src="#">
        <img id="img2" src="#">
        <img id="img3" src="#">
    </div>
    <button id="next">Next</button>
</div>
</div>
```

**JavaScript**

```
$.getJSON("item-data.json", function(results) {
        $.each(results.CatalogEntryView, function(index, item) {

            document.getElementById("productImage").src = item.Images[0].PrimaryImage[0].image;
            document.getElementById("img1").src = item.Images[0].AlternateImages[0].image;
            document.getElementById("img2").src = item.Images[0].AlternateImages[1].image;
            document.getElementById("img3").src = item.Images[0].AlternateImages[2].image;

        });

        //Map Array for Slideshow
     var slideShowArray = results.CatalogEntryView.map(item => item.Images.map(imgs =>[imgs.PrimaryImage[0].image, ...imgs.AlternateImages.map(alt => alt.image)]))[0][0];

        //Slideshow functions
            var num = 0
            function next() {
                var slider = document.getElementById("productImage");
                var carouselImg1 = document.getElementById("img1");
                var carouselImg2 = document.getElementById("img2");
                var carouselImg3 = document.getElementById("img3");
                num++
                if(num >= slideShowArray.length)
                    {num = 0}
                            productImage.src = slideShowArray[num];
                            img1.src = slideShowArray[num-1];
                            img2.src = slideShowArray[num];
                            img3.src = slideShowArray[num+1];
            }

            function prev() {
                var slider = document.getElementById("productImage");
                var carouselImg1 = document.getElementById("img1");
                var carouselImg2 = document.getElementById("img2");
                var carouselImg3 = document.getElementById("img3");
                num--;
                if(num < 0) {
                    num = slideShowArray.length-1;
                }
                productImage.src = slideShowArray[num];
                        img1.src = slideShowArray[num-1];
                        img2.src = slideShowArray[num];
                        img3.src = slideShowArray[num+1];
            }

        //Event Listeners
            document.getElementById("next").addEventListener("click", next)
            document.getElementById("prev").addEventListener("click", prev)

            });
```

**CSS Placeholder Code to Shrink the Thumbnails**

```
#img1, #img2, #img3 {
    height: 50px;
    width: 50px;
}
```

**JSON**

This fiddle will show you the relevant JSON data in `item-data.json`: https://jsfiddle.net/kdd1gppz/

Answer (score 0):

```
if(num >= slideShowArray.length)
                {num = 0}
productImage.src = slideShowArray[num];
img1.src = slideShowArray[num-1];
img2.src = slideShowArray[num];
img3.src = slideShowArray[num+1];
```

And

```
if(num < 0) {
    num = slideShowArray.length-1;
}
productImage.src = slideShowArray[num];
img1.src = slideShowArray[num-1];
img2.src = slideShowArray[num];
img3.src = slideShowArray[num+1];
```

Problems are here. When n = 0, you try to read `slideShowArray[-1]` and when n = slideShowArray.length - 1, you try to read `slideShowArray[slideShowArray.length]`. Both doesn't exit, this is why you get undefined values. You have to bound `num` value between `[0; slideShowArray.length - 1]` (ie : if n = -1 => n = slideShowArray.length - 1, if n = slideShowArray.length => n = 0)

Modulo operator should help you

[Solution]

Add a function :

```
function getIndex(num, offset, arrayLength) {
    // Add arrayLength prevents negative number test case
    return (num + arrayLength + offset) % arrayLength;
}
```

Remove your `if` statements.

When you do `num++ / num--`, replace by `num = getIndex(num, +/-1, slideShowArray.length)`

When you tried to access to `slideShowArray`, replace direct access by `slideShowArray[getIndex(num, +/-1, slideShowArray.length)]`

The only strong limitation is to not start `num` to a negative value < `slideShowArray.length`

Comment: So which one for the function next () and which one for the function prev()? So tired right now I can't think straight lol

Comment: You actually didn't tell me anything new. (ie : if n = -1 => n = slideShowArray.length - 1, if n = slideShowArray.length => n = 0) is the same exact logic I already have

Comment: Ok I see. Thanks for the response.

Answer (score 0):

This worked. Created variables stepup and step down:

```
            var num = 0
            function next() {
                var slider = document.getElementById("productImage");
                var carouselImg1 = document.getElementById("img1");
                var carouselImg2 = document.getElementById("img2");
                var carouselImg3 = document.getElementById("img3");
//
                num++
                if(num >= slideShowArray.length)
                    {num = 0}

                var stepup = num + 1;
                var stepdown = num -1;

                if(stepup >= slideShowArray.length)
                    {stepup = 0}
                if(stepdown < 0)
                    {stepdown = slideShowArray.length-1}

                            productImage.src = slideShowArray[num];
                            img1.src = slideShowArray[stepdown];
                            img2.src = slideShowArray[num];
                            img3.src = slideShowArray[stepup];

            }

            function prev() {
                var slider = document.getElementById("productImage");
                var carouselImg1 = document.getElementById("img1");
                var carouselImg2 = document.getElementById("img2");
                var carouselImg3 = document.getElementById("img3");
                //
                num--;
                if(num < 0) {
                    num = slideShowArray.length-1;
                }

                var stepup = num + 1;
                var stepdown = num -1;

                if(stepup >= slideShowArray.length)
                    {stepup = 0}
                if(stepdown < 0)
                    {stepdown = slideShowArray.length-1}

                productImage.src = slideShowArray[num];
                        img1.src = slideShowArray[stepdown];
                        img2.src = slideShowArray[num];
                        img3.src = slideShowArray[stepup];

            }
```